# Meaning and purpose of this line in Javascript - star[t][0] > x << 1 && (star[t][0] -= w << 1, test = !1)

Tags: javascript

I saw a canvas animation in the header at following url - 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2011/07/21/html5-gaming-animating-sprites-in-canvas-with-easeljs.aspx

A jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anmolsaraf/bQUwn/2/)

While going through the javascript code a few annoying lines have a taken of lot of hours in understanding them, still having no luck and left with the only option to ask the experts at StackOverflow.

The lines are ( Line 85 - 90 in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anmolsaraf/bQUwn/2/) ) -

```
 star[t][0] += mouse_x >> 4, 
 star[t][0] > x << 1 && (star[t][0] -= w << 1, test = !1), 
 star[t][0] < -x << 1 && (star[t][0] += w << 1, test = !1),
```

All this runs in a for loop. The major confusing point for me is, making those two comparisons at line 2 and 3 above after an assignment in line 1. What's the purpose of this when the result of these two comparisons at line 2 and 3 above isn't stored into any variable ?

Comment: Those are bitwise operators not comparitors. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: Yes I know the bitwise operators but by comparison I meant the &&. Also the '>' and '<' operators in the above lines making it confusing for me to understand it as a whole. Anyway, thanks for looking into this problem. Appreciate it.

Comment: yes you are right @csharpler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"What's the purpose of this when the result of these two comparisons at line 2 and 3 above isn't stored into any variable ?"*

It's using `&&` as a short-hand for `if`, because the `&&` operator first evaluates the left-hand operand and only if that is truthy does it evaluate the right hand operand.

The line:

```
star[t][0] > x << 1 && (star[t][0] -= w << 1, test = !1)
```

could be rewritten as:

```
if (star[t][0] > x << 1) {
   star[t][0] -= w << 1, test = !1;
}
```

(And similar for the third line.)

As an aside, `!1` is shorthand for `false`.

Comment: well, `true` BOOLEAN cannot always `1` but in most cases it is `1` and sometimes it is other number.

Comment: @AspiringAqib `!1` is _always_ `false` because of how the `!` operator works on non-boolean values. This is not the same as saying that `1` is equal to `true`.

Comment: so I guess what is returned from this line - (star[t][0] -= w << 1, test = !1) will always be false because comma operator will execute both the operands but will return the last one, which here is test = !1 and with && comparison the overall result will be false or this whole line is just for executing ---> star[t][0] -= w << 1 <--- if the first operand before the && is true ? let me know if I am not correctly explaining this..

Comment: Since the expression isn't being assigned anywhere or returned, it doesn't matter what the return value is. The expression is just being executed for its side effect of setting `star[t][0]` and `test`.

Comment: Great, all doubts cleared now. Thanks everybody, especially @nnnnnn for looking into this. That's the reason StackOverflow rocks because of the expert help that we get here. Thanks again :)